# How to Insert data to Many to many relationship tables and retrieving last id In cases where the method accepts two parameters?

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-room, dao

Room does return the inserted id when the input has only one parameter

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWithDrinks(item: DrinkFavourite): Long
```

How can i retrieve the ID when method looks like this

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWithDrinks(item: DrinkFavourite, List<Drink>)
```

Or rather, How do you handle many-to-many relationship Insert? I have a relationship and a cross ref table like this

```
data class DrinkFavouritesWithDrinks(
    @Embedded
    val item: DrinkFavourite,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "item_id",
        entityColumn = "drink_id",
        associateBy = Junction(DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef::class)
    )
    val drinks: List<Drink> = emptyList()
)
```

my cross ref

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["item_id", "drink_id"]
)
data class DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    val itemId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "drink_id")
    val drinkId: Int
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i retrieve the ID when method looks like this

When you insert multiple rows you get the resultant id's in an `Array<Long>`

However, for a basic cross reference/mapping table you would rarely, it ever, use the **rowid** column (which is the value returned).

- **rowid** is returned even though the column is implicitly defined. That is with the exception of rarely used WITHOUT ROWID tables, all tables have a hidden column named **rowid**.

  - When you use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to define a column, the column is an alias of the **rowid** column. In room @PrimaryKey for a Long or Int, with or without `autoGenerate = true/false` (without = false) equates to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or if `autoGenerate = true` to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.

> How do you handle many-to-many relationship Insert?

Here is an example, based upon the available code, with other code created.

So in addition to your DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef Entity.

Entities for DrinkFavourite and Item  are

```
@Entity
 data class DrinkFavourite(
    @PrimaryKey
    val drink_id: Int? = null,
    val drink_name: String = ""
)
@Entity
```

data class Drink(
    @PrimaryKey var itemId :Long?,
    var itemName: String
)

The Dao **AllDao** is :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertDrinkFavourite(drinkFavourite: DrinkFavourite) :Long

    @Insert
    fun insertManyDrinkFavourite(drinkFavourites: List<DrinkFavourite>) :Array<Long>

    @Insert
    fun insertItem(drink: Drink) :Long

    @Insert
    fun insertManyItems(drinks: List<Drink>) :Array<Long>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertDrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef(drinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef: DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef) :Long

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertManyDrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef(drinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRefs: List<DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef>) :Array<Long>
}
```

- This caters for inserting a single Entity/row and many Entity/rows for each of the 3 Entities.

The following utilises the 3 many insertions defined in the Dao to insert 3 `Drink`s, 4 `DrinkFavourite`s and to then insert the 12 `DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef`s (3 `Drink` * 4 `DrinkFavorite`) permutations, i.e. all possible permutations, that can be crossed referenced based upon the id's inserted.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var database: Database

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, Database::class.java, "drinksdb")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        //val firsItemtid = database.allDao().insertItem( Item(0,"X"))
        val manyItemIds = database.allDao().insertManyItems(
            listOf(
                Drink(null,"A"),
                Drink(null,"B"),
                Drink(null,"C")
            )
        )
        val manyDrinkFavouriteIds = database.allDao().insertManyDrinkFavourite(
            listOf(
                DrinkFavourite(null,"DrinkA"),
                DrinkFavourite(null,"DrinkB"),
                DrinkFavourite(null,"DrinkC"),
                DrinkFavourite(null,"DrinkD")
            )
        )

        var xrefcombos = ArrayList<DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef>()
        for(itemId: Long in manyItemIds) {
            for (dfId: Long in manyDrinkFavouriteIds) {
                xrefcombos.add( DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef(itemId,dfId.toInt()))
            }
        }
        val drinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRefIdList = database.allDao().insertManyDrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef(xrefcombos)
        for (dfadcrId in drinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRefIdList) {
            Log.d("DRKFAVDRNKXREF","Id = " + dfadcrId)
        }
    }
}
```

The output is :-

```
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 1
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 2
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 3
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 4
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 5
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 6
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 7
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 8
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 9
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 10
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 11
2020-01-17 07:46:40.621 D/DRKFAVDRNKXREF: Id = 12
```

i.e the 12 permutations have been added.

I don't believe that you can effectively use `@Insert` to do other than insertions according to the Entity/Object being inserted. To do more complex insertions based upon other values, you would use `@Query` with suitable SQL.

## Additional

With regard to :-

```
data class DrinkFavouritesWithDrinks(
    @Embedded
    val item: DrinkFavourite,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "item_id",
        entityColumn = "drink_id",
        associateBy = Junction(DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef::class)
    )
```

I believe that this should be :-

```
data class DrinkFavouriteWithDrinks (

    @Embedded
    val drinkFavourite: DrinkFavourite,
    @Relation(
        entity =  Drink::class,
        entityColumn = "itemId",
        parentColumn = "drink_id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            DrinkFavouriteAndDrinksCrossRef::class,entityColumn = "item_id",parentColumn = "drink_id"))
    val drinks: List<Drink> = emptyList()
    )
```

- You get all the Drinks per DrinkFavourite, so singular rather than plural is a better name.
- the association needs to know the columns to associate by.

You could than have a Dao method such as :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM drinkfavourite")
fun getAllDrinkFavouritesWithDrinks() :List<DrinkFavouriteWithDrinks>
```

Adding to the following to the MainActivity above :-

```
    val drinkFavouriteWithDrinksList = database.allDao().getAllDrinkFavouritesWithDrinks()
    var sb = StringBuilder()
    for (dfwd: DrinkFavouriteWithDrinks in drinkFavouriteWithDrinksList) {
        sb.clear().append("DrinkFavourite = ").append(dfwd.drinkFavourite)
        for (d: Drink in dfwd.drinks) {
            sb.append("\n\tDrink = ").append(d.itemName)
        }
        Log.d("DRINKFAVINFO", sb.toString())
    }
```

Results in :-

> ```
> 2020-01-17 11:39:52.762 D/DRINKFAVINFO: DrinkFavourite = DrinkFavourite(drink_id=1, drinkFavouriteName=DrinkA)
>       Drink = A
>       Drink = B
>       Drink = C
> 2020-01-17 11:39:52.763 D/DRINKFAVINFO: DrinkFavourite = DrinkFavourite(drink_id=2, drinkFavouriteName=DrinkB)
>       Drink = A
>       Drink = B
>       Drink = C
> 2020-01-17 11:39:52.763 D/DRINKFAVINFO: DrinkFavourite = DrinkFavourite(drink_id=3, drinkFavouriteName=DrinkC)
>       Drink = A
>       Drink = B
>       Drink = C
> 2020-01-17 11:39:52.763 D/DRINKFAVINFO: DrinkFavourite = DrinkFavourite(drink_id=4, drinkFavouriteName=DrinkD)
>       Drink = A
>       Drink = B
>       Drink = C
> ```

- *Not the best example as every DrinkFavourite has all three drinks*